# How can I read List of objects in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

How can I read below result in angularjs in controller.js

```
{
   "placeList":[
      [
         {
            "address":null,
            "name":"Len The Plumber"
         },
         {
            "address":null,
            "name":"Pete The Plumber"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

I want to read items in priceList and companyList.

Tried with :

```
$scope.allresultsfinal = PostFactory.allresults.query({tag: $scope.UserPost.postText}
```

And

```
<li ng-repeat="all in allresultsfinal.placeList"> {{ all.name }} </li>
```

but didn't work and tried different combinations as well but no joy!

Please let me know how can I read JSON structure above?

UPDATE AFTER MAKING ARRAY CHANGES:

```
{"placeList":[{"address":null,"name":"Len The Plumber","id":"68ce5955681aeac79de1164a75e82163fe6308fc","reference":"CoQBcgAAADoXKm8tL_QZaqqFozoZIjKhA74vbBJt_ZZApl4rwIEheboKkNKX8SaFhQPB3WvospgbMbJZwQO_jzYTVtT_ppC_TPuaSIGectkiF12f3IyizfDs3eEytZFe70w9V9wQB1tiJEkihWYvXJJkyidsbq1kRAGZ4ewmlK2mzeEwIKx0EhD2nELXzgfur0aKgULVj4deGhQU47YfM0t0RjTdWuy2ASuLY9-Gtw","latitude":39.274644,"longitude":-76.629542,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.5,"reviews":null,"openNow":null,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CpQBgQAAAIuEtFtu5N2JH2NowGrSdTpUucwbHcetA-oBOzvTsXKoCt07YnoKT9BvihyC6To_eOS3vagwjnUrEBryXA1EQ7sDNvW8CTaR-c6_BOevBOG8kNtzCNLW6YB24shoKhsN4133uP7CUMGiej5riYpF1bTpVuqCvdgeOW5Q9Jygtu6BHAho3cMP7sT5UWqoPWz5ZBIQsI1Q80EUkTp4srSG6XW71BoUmnlcK-yhFb-ebpDZoJQxo5vryCY","height":1360,"width":2048,"htmlAttributions":["<a href=\"https://plus.google.com/113953784289827095588\">Sondra Stegemann</a>"]}],"formattedAddress":"Baltimore, MD, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Pete The Plumber","id":"9806e0608fd2eb5f6cd32d30d463cdf3cfc0e9a5","reference":"CoQBcgAAAAHw8sDJYXLQZr5f_DtV10UyCd8gCUXbVRcEh6oUS-lvXw-vPuG-w5aj-sU-WJVFrcM3WBlfl3wnNjSlbHPQiA28JV8OJnJsGWOTxT0QR0-9Crh1ItpHOeDNOnWV6_tSCxTzKHBxVMkQUhUMtPWuFtQVf0vKbLF9dit1pzSie45EEhDYwsIfUZtuK7y5-iLj2JzPGhRJ8jSHYb3EyXLjMUadBX2xOB6zIw","latitude":50.951891,"longitude":-113.970987,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":3.9,"reviews":null,"openNow":false,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CnRnAAAAXjXZr4uKCAjc_P8vtHMNWjw8DR2ymh0crQ6R94PpAAdM18-hWSHJKBLHDFvjV5XsZXBvCeXKnKEjpI1VeYt_uMhHsigQIx6qZbPWVc8pqCxZWjWMwBGxvP57svNrg8c9uaWXVm7xufhwNcgzS7JEChIQUUeim-4SL-YnGT_lKVjBGxoU7bKtOym0xxLXWSPRtaHh-DbZecQ","height":161,"width":215,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"4550 112 Ave SE, Calgary, AB, Canada","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["store","plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Benjamin Franklin Plumbing Twin Cities","id":"b0f38753a78291b8a7cfa3fd363efe3e2a93f63f","reference":"CpQBiQAAAHzXp89UNlCnOYd5L0I2luNj4yblbG19ixChoUmKqKGtJY1mr4NuVCYHOd8RuLjx-h1bqFlBHhxNxXy7ABHYXze0WJcs8Y67yOzs9SNuVbF3nZCHwk49c_3_Ers5a_koQAHLWYPzCAYvA2EnzRJnsJD7dmI5nUPJ6sJ5TXL19q8jhXVSUfppNwgolyQRa1netxIQWXh4naiXpUb_pKSjDLeizxoU1dwd2lp93UNBEtPtdNWOHuL4SxA","latitude":44.99337,"longitude":-93.282932,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.3,"reviews":null,"openNow":null,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CnRnAAAAp3VD7Y2wdvi0tqusfypYvqpg-NYwVLV-VGdo9ZP9gpzPk9JORNR_3J0An6IuEXurAWL87KTr0o2q4fOr8wB9ZhfcncBmaEONlPVY43Kl0RHhQ9ctPtFLlVeSS8vqefKmx1ldiJvU9Doa-SooBPXBRxIQee2a8aKYbwLb4NzbgjIFsBoUUHcF48_4vIQEaOK0cCkVzvczzwQ","height":864,"width":996,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"1424 N 3rd St, Minneapolis, MN, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["store","plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Spartan Plumbing, Heating and Air Conditioning","id":"80eecdbfb66ff75c1b461d0ca6690fe15c7618c3","reference":"CpQBkAAAACqxzWLYjUZYHHPPj51Pc_84Bw1IVwGNhGxyb3PKuz8a52cPQDYsGUdTg5o6jsrtGTSsPo9WSp1axn-XSN9Cr93XdQYq7gLqarO64FHAARUvKxtyHBIRVSBl03L5Kn3cbFMjV7WNJjkxHqhsW41poE9WWrNAuK6rYNFplgCz1wJGuGxu2NoisWYg6jRgd7NclBIQegU2fVgp-luhPNlP82gB8hoUEw2sU-Jkjo_TFeTAG3Q6TERcqS0","latitude":38.908787,"longitude":-77.027239,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.6,"reviews":null,"openNow":false,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CqQBngAAAOtwwljV6BUyMzQEEnFXrO653KlML9vNeJ1eYR5Unwb3CoWKFF7T4ADkMOh5hf8D-kPSkayxxv5I-nwGW7nlXJ6mOazfexL-YMME_-AIZfhqkpavqPOXqlayZt2mMjEH-8cwy7Q1Xztm0v9Gy1PK7aM49wXlqcXpM8fzL5WKHxynB5qapJza_PLAckacGFonJd_O_Y0NKZX-EGbB2rzj9twSEAWf9WNXagEecQ4zA5FXQYEaFBv-WW37J-UW_2xeN3kVxj04gO2f","height":200,"width":300,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"1776 I Street, NW #900, Washington, DC, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Bell Plumbing & Heating Company","id":"39015ba7fa6e5dffb12948bf15254b279291b01d","reference":"CpQBggAAANen7uzm5gqVr0ABvT5kQDf8IYl6VJ6j9E1SAyK2f2ehbVFeO6Kb9fOoNUGmnxsYMzEBCE4RyV1EZHhm8hEjcmtFKg7EreM2JCYKYVfesu2oBVQWxV2fM93qKxVJnVcHM5Tuz1U--sbQSkvIlI6oJ68d_FQcnrNJK_uu9ZpXUs505wuiBsK2xuX12H_zsZ2_SxIQg2-UoXqV-qYXMkkkqaEY9RoU_cDNteVqty1_l1jmRf0tuV_AsME","latitude":39.677725,"longitude":-104.826517,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.2,"reviews":null,"openNow":true,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CnRnAAAAtXaWasdyoExEkFoE-98psIdsD5_2Vc52G2NS-Mth12OUiSabCap79aaiHsVCqDi3GzOXAzt64Ic6laDKbEwxXNb8xekJi0R3PAUK870HxYwwAaW_rTiusw27e0BP-Xo26uwth98Yo5hj5STdK9t2ihIQPzuvbHVQJyjVVmMOGkp6XhoUaawKUL3LXFSppEOh5ZTzVpmLG4M","height":403,"width":604,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"2150 S Abilene St, Aurora, CO, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png","types":["general_contractor","plumber","home_goods_store","store","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Abacus Plumbing & Air Conditioning","id":"5f5178b50c72b6810470b1345f7fd190dc52f479","reference":"CpQBhQAAAJz5wpqUQYx6M8K4921h3X3licmU2-NT7hbAs5bc4IbcekchOuNvm6Lax_nzhmIz9hpMk6OKU4PW6QfnO7OoBCPJFhIwi3IJYsPqUdtWcu1exgnq9yHLlXv6jUwOOEDfN3N644SaDMKSUO_VtXI-uHPe4s2iwCxtQh_ymsRnu_dGSAk1eSbpVx7f7-HH_dYYZRIQuAFxej0C5LnZKeFoiLLXBxoUKZyl2yBvNzcfSPIdaFiJ2eIUkW8","latitude":29.949188,"longitude":-95.315495,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.8,"reviews":null,"openNow":true,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CoQBfwAAAGaknJnYxszrLa5gp6GGNTgz7lZBx2vrL-oWtO-x9QuldQeaEFZrU0U4-9kTKeqG-LcIlfUiJ6IX_5PpJ_-nraAu6wnCdTi7-ZJ5qVvhX4hnCv6573n_HVBEE0qRyzWhx3LsAloTJ9PYZS3-zO27DeLUSUgyOMM6k2OSYSwx3CP3EhAbqFmyv1bbTvkZlnX9KXiOGhTLUF-sxw5U13OYFGvDigrogQOrsA","height":1557,"width":2048,"htmlAttributions":["<a href=\"https://plus.google.com/107888555485993681638\">Alan O&#39;Neill</a>"]}],"formattedAddress":"15851 Vickery Dr, Houston, TX, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png","types":["general_contractor","plumber","home_goods_store","store","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Aramendia Plumbing Heating & Air","id":"72ad80f537f0fbf23e447aec7d8c6a9ea238c3d5","reference":"CpQBggAAAGAxQWta7ZYHWWMdmoJe4rLoOIkyCyzCyVYuYhd_LhZsgCebsFK61DLtKlPG7b91lB4IvWeB_50fUuZaPlrdQinqQlIBmbGKaoMf15Cv2YX3ODArzSgb8F2lV689phC2j97AaY5KbxytPMFT0Im2rh5Tx9m4hUoY9Yc7YuFiGdbLKEWEzHpnr35Os1LM1VsefhIQ1KKT1tWUlMQJijtXY5eM6BoU1lZJ6zC21OlX_f_KoLYN2V9h-94","latitude":29.541232,"longitude":-98.381041,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":3.6,"reviews":null,"openNow":true,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CnRnAAAAwDqG0L-E9PQEZjNmwVSjOFUrfeaZtmuEG3DYQSUwK5HZjfcVK0nlY_lAfot7_SvLxwrgT7G2F1DrdHPdfl5MscfVeREZn9s2NokzSsSUT982W51mR8KuMcNmL035k2_XiltzvE-hkBF-9YCrvsv7LBIQa_qyfX3OZuHavnkJF9Ms-RoUXNHTopx9-Lzfnho1GfCDBvSbpdo","height":282,"width":425,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"5511 Brewster St, San Antonio, TX, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"A. J. Michaels","id":"6ad1e733e64274f6878ac9154429c96b73def7fd","reference":"CoQBcQAAAJCu1Z2XfhmwkmfdrsxeUSuD35wlKB5CvGxE6EwYrY5S2CMX6TRdqSXaV-hVoBheX8-He_UCI2t60mP3oY3cp3VLL0WCvNA7KyRYyw4O1aBkXNhUWpvuJWokyTpZRqB25edGBMUy_GyR5cub8spQVex-424zMPWm38tGfFXuozmvEhAoKvUoE3E3VrdJomKvdDAEGhT9pLxKlI7wPGw2pPKJdsIom93QAw","latitude":39.344039,"longitude":-76.609781,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":3.3,"reviews":null,"openNow":false,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CoQBcwAAADI8pSUhg-sjDvHOS4ODulwTq3RSnNjchZoX8S88ty39pqIjYyv85k9jVvIev4h-Og7a9RUzUl2cf9DHIvfmV7mdchZ0OipDuuE9b-1XbGjAVa2H0sdGLouVmWV2GbFaOoB2S60jPgSYOsG9T5eD5Ps3K9whd4KyhM8EY46GZg5KEhC8xm34eFiHvfU006H0kAmXGhRadZDEBBe3CEBcvYgN-W47bgKtqw","height":225,"width":300,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"4512 York Rd, Baltimore, MD, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png","types":["general_contractor","plumber","home_goods_store","store","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Holt Plumbing Co., LLC","id":"e7b1cfd226a598fbdf85c0c0d3ab0a33bf9112f6","reference":"CoQBeQAAABQwpgLT09s4cnzqRN1i0msC3Ix5qmv4Rzqmoms-g_y2kfR2X86NxcJDKvRlDMJ2V-64KZSywZU0VuXndO2XRFwSyWLTvgFnn95lLtnr_0tSaUEYiMVkAlHmEQIrmtLAcNdH8YiTpqp_NzJeh08kBLlyhUoxsyyUuqRiGTht0M-tEhBl8EH2A7pgDNNR5CQSA6FoGhTa0-PcMfUPwynfLM9rxZ67nzZNAw","latitude":36.151228,"longitude":-86.673433,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.2,"reviews":null,"openNow":null,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CnRnAAAAxI4ZkwS7uls2G84fQJfS41UYFvdoFwFt_I0yc5Xgdan4u1elvNATHU6ayJ_LVyNOeE5TLaOKn83UbLSse0gRpGCyMSCb8ei2M0BShty7O2SHGPMgPGXTT0FVhy2GDZ5DErOpfQKZclsiuQHat4wdNxIQQDun971FMDcppfbopFcXjxoUmUujUMNcdiT7tN7xuftPdLGzzrk","height":128,"width":175,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"Nashville, TN, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"C Anderson & Sons","id":"1679b35fc8b92ad2cb19bcccd62f86e3c41ef2e6","reference":"CoQBdAAAANV2v237Ohe82V11i9XSpb5LXPPl7Whp4aRo073veTJuCvr9Ag4cu1qhbjvlHBDAqaIpJBvLXjwoQVSYYiipx9N19UktfySh1LBNIB_u7ITaf8Yzsj0OPpoPNDMdWGryoQRnS14FbOWcTgOj9-UCe0lSHaSCO_YUjL0vtzmwwP_OEhAUfJiEtHvd7e5xeGgnD6AJGhSeZ__OaI9QgUfbl7_sV5ZpMv1gbw","latitude":51.479721,"longitude":-0.207459,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.0,"reviews":null,"openNow":true,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CnRnAAAAkim1GQCuxeZ1BBX14UD_Z4HFKlLyC2pOaVePehH1njoCytH32u0OG6ceS-whEaiCrnTO1hv0BdGZ9if0-Zp2JFYUqKYMBE8yHHgzyXHBsk_AvkEn2e70myGxKufBXcdxg5brCaancxBcUwXZ_k7RBhIQCXb7R3hNbU_dNVVwXV2AxRoUdh_UqDsi0WVO-XB702lkzkf4FEk","height":335,"width":530,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"25-27 Filmer Rd, London, United Kingdom","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png","types":["general_contractor","plumber","home_goods_store","store","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Pimlico Plumbers","id":"8062fe5810ffaa733ce504072ca3295966332e94","reference":"CoQBcgAAAO2MC7ALolmHyt7MtQErt4G7xihkJmDvf8ib096xs1l_pnSzhHqqyrzgWLaA11ZZbxulUQnhgw7KOmBWcmgXG12O_e0ig0ZSrI4CySlg6CHq9p2bioaJ3YKhvcySDvmOu5m0Np8Nsk8MLJf1YTWjZyMRuDSxvNOVYUICj9JxDTuAEhA3g1-TDSXCNw-0sLG9ABdMGhTOF3rmkZ5tZi3dPhjKXt4yAw9VFA","latitude":51.494874,"longitude":-0.115856,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":3.5,"reviews":null,"openNow":true,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CnRnAAAA50_GnNSc9llmBg5SREcAVcO-UR0oWuoQi8LV0sJV7RJtDnvSm-CPLZktlTl_20ba1jKYZToFGra8gmgKb3HwAcLcl0eGawuQHdnyd6LRNvNJQxkBFcxRYgsbNwvZYjwDGJqF3qvIvnJ1qEm-6K5slhIQPFq3cWKPltXHjkgvHFsw8xoUlCMylqYTW3fwjIn6tUKD3vUOuPY","height":620,"width":938,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"Pimlico House, 1 Sail St, London, United Kingdom","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["roofing_contractor","electrician","locksmith","plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Benjamin Franklin Plumbing","id":"f8d721226559cecbb165265bb1974d0c1d5ec1b7","reference":"CoQBfQAAAFCKKEX7rrdSRr02tLr7yy4YXL_nuTidKURZWbs-awNfqBmumEPmxv3657u3Nb2KpFBftHvhxrSHHcRKvatppz1aGOoSMot-9pXole7UDeyZCtEMeZPj4O46nnqhSsced9SuJeXL76Xe9ogbBX933Wa_hNBC-oCuITjPJPODMIfIEhAo4sJyKxJQeVFFVAjVh94ZGhSyDRgxeUrZub6cbSqsFlvwkXnk0Q","latitude":39.74872,"longitude":-86.02525,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":1.7,"reviews":null,"openNow":true,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CnRnAAAASDc2PB7kuLjpZJtSHC8AHh1bEVTXGnXmcJLZzyHZxElCZ4o8HLRAvEw1Fz4uLoK016k7Bv7MUiO7m7t51yAJwSMICYeAydWxFu-ivS-0pw4_fWKPakvy3UZZTUpZ73CEPC20hgY2s_c-BCKeEQPWZxIQ68K1H4llAA8Wn9_wsVf7XBoUZsuddPrODTPxpfGsOfalWjdXPx0","height":500,"width":500,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"Indianapolis, IN, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Terry's Plumbing, Inc.","id":"fa8f6ce8e8f741246eaa653b31cc22fa4c29f880","reference":"CoQBeAAAALRsQpj9FovJW6bO5-JYuJSeVl6qcPxVZMe8sx4h3_zxsYIuWmeGWTD_flIp2HSoUivip2acISgvmbwjca388ZfEN5I41dmUTIBLAaElpPOTdg2PR9msbgXGRwXbWMWHAjvmxC31xHngyxQtJ3ZCKzl5UX2gjaGIrvBEKYGhryEvEhCKAMNaJJ0j3gpAzlvhYbfmGhRY6NiMajXJ1DiakLZU6jbIpO53xQ","latitude":40.52509,"longitude":-80.017018,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.7,"reviews":null,"openNow":false,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CnRnAAAAs-rwRpyC020biDPdK_gc7k2sai2VEYY6u4rCPtpuggEOIjYv8HiRRfkVj2BRxGPa34qsfTsE-6uOUd4RkdBcl_o6UG9SxJTo7R67N_fju4nJ6uUkeapS3BUW8HfMafy9y-csMq7WsnCxyfrUGAez0xIQMAZM5z2Sm3TZU96Y_BHcOBoUGR5wzG0TWufmGLNL8r0BId6EO90","height":682,"width":1024,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"3227 Babcock Blvd, Pittsburgh, PA, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png","types":["general_contractor","plumber","home_goods_store","store","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Apex Plumbing","id":"3c9b9735bf70d1dd20d3b89cb88478ea50c6d096","reference":"CnRwAAAAtzguF7DRlDjHq68rcisgpMlgZyYKvsRkQu3Fvye5R7BDdTbWiLkN4DZQsM-oJ8sZVZXoBN-bMByDaQDXFVrI7fIjEd_rWyYRfh6e1sqTHA4zC6KMLYpWYIPgYLyADLu_tskitOIkxcpFync8CeGl2hIQGzgbxRaVKTv67Bw4zPkJXhoUMhmLD7Shhl4i-cMyTN5exS6rZbw","latitude":41.953804,"longitude":-87.706418,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.9,"reviews":null,"openNow":true,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CoQBeQAAAC5AozV_qBUw31nsD8ZpZsSgSN3rXGqlketah6_WErPsgUIEfqXZuZ1NX5ayAkXWtsIUaykj2H4JDyYFx9iG_iZg-aA9YQCjECN7TEyKa5Whck8rF9YGFIYYX8FWQ4G53RB8A90EwcVQa3x5tT35jK9oLsEXd-3n3J2LPh64P4A6EhBVaodRhvvEf8M2fTvU7UB_GhSE8Ae4XKKWDrQZ7ssliriYwPL1OA","height":1152,"width":2048,"htmlAttributions":["<a href=\"https://plus.google.com/110089776889034187380\">Charles Osleber</a>"]}],"formattedAddress":"3119 Irving Park Rd, Chicago, IL, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["general_contractor","plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Fox Plumbing & Heating","id":"150d6443bdaeb8dc1841adff63be5637a34b8de5","reference":"CoQBeAAAAC0GQq3UqC2bx0NTSmtxBkN-lv11oI4kiB83z0cKsktfAZgFXZAg6VV8AsME-lqZnrBbIDfZfyLeC9fqmk3uufbESnQyrAz_oNZBJ2OGfWM27-meGMInxq9XaAoNU6GOPAnNTDNnD2Ll5xqjhysa0iWKm7TASX64NEz0vggLMra8EhDFsMBf12DZ53A1HRySg5WxGhSt0jlq5Nk3BKCoN2hWpxG4Tt0xmA","latitude":47.535489,"longitude":-122.331765,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.8,"reviews":null,"openNow":false,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CnRnAAAAYcdmghDjvsqxEQz9fQPnxb4XqKcR2RH4w2AuUDrhvsZDc18tki2a0njttAwPXbLRhipXayn8YuCQjI7ACRIQ_l19Jg6xWIR73JKYxHJrXF7BjgUlW2HmD0CT5rfI3o9mCJAylNA8Rk9f2ufJ5fobORIQF9YDjvFFX44uK69Fj45xGRoUXTDYKICnBGEkQsGe5PBVKxwH9xI","height":381,"width":577,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"7501 2nd Ave S, Seattle, WA, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png","types":["general_contractor","plumber","home_goods_store","store","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Rainforest Plumbing & Air","id":"d58d852122e39d33a4fe588561877a9af01bdb18","reference":"CoQBfAAAADpKlNVqXHp53kR-TPJDJyd-VElcNy7L5ejbb3w6mNDQPJzd001Qha7SkwImvug3p8NzJq82-NdWqPQQQU3PFdRV05rwgQY0TwQJeP4bbVMvVnsz1mtfUh4kgfsgPRnwteJw4XwesKiSSWOBVJl3WpF9KZCn216XY3fsL7a4rl1_EhDKevqnmUrd9AOEWkw7ov4KGhRy1KR1prrcw2aAhBzO7TgHBmzctg","latitude":33.300857,"longitude":-111.970018,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.9,"reviews":null,"openNow":true,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CpQBhAAAAGJTyRvZNFFT8ufGGryB3td_ef0ize2PggajQ9bK732jWR_hMSrDn3fXdolwRfZSu8bdG3w6fyhbkN9lQYx4rHuDzsod31V0woZwyxac8h-pOZ86Xmul7T2um1CEDQparhECW7Dt25JImvyTnYqerE4Mf8yIYwofbrR_Rl4nNku3mTZU99IpZLnptEdqX5WtkRIQYejG5p14A-KJSt2mToosmxoUhmQot-q8iTJQKJ2cJoml6HWkBsA","height":1200,"width":1800,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"127 S Weber Dr, Chandler, AZ, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Milani Plumbing, Drainage and Heating","id":"fb154a0e342135f1b0d0882e96041696e3779edd","reference":"CpQBhwAAABIn5uTwVt2_RP1tWnbdfdHh8_NQo2dtouGhVvlpKepRnxDPHAbwiLX-2mlCFlpOTQMgKYdTVnXukEIA-VdU4RWU6UMT7TbJOQldmzepMoF9KX7MeB4teH64y5XaczPfKrpkPRwQpDsz-GGyy8GiIo0bX2mZvFvLrlQlIIrknRCsE87_3_z5LCOm8ScdGSrSrxIQbVeoTtNFiz8mZ9PcVwDu2hoUKGn76xEjtdc8DNj73LiFogdd7Us","latitude":49.223408,"longitude":-122.984293,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.5,"reviews":null,"openNow":true,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CqQBkwAAAMmjVpIbWQBaKZw3psL_97TihUDxbBxW-WqNicf5XiXTZWh-FB8SOV6E7ATSDBW2leUfTUYRirUeqOZ_Qd4xfvH6bHpdWdjhUee1jZixORC12tkYnUb0y7u9zZnIVplWa_Xeekc5L5GhtopAqXPgaqxjmjqqqVctUkz-hLsBlwtOCDVm7GsTNJsHxpqVJ-jhxrsH-jztwG1JnO5bZyQlVmwSEAkw5RQrAZFwIpohI0y547saFHImQF035VNSA5Y6h69SJpYVnpKs","height":225,"width":263,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"5526 Kingsway, Burnaby, BC, Canada","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"The Plumber","id":"f724b7a587b5910dcf86b7eb955feff999c803c8","reference":"CnRtAAAAyc5Z9bK1CWBI0RSU_T7rGOoyOLGubuK9TnlKiC-ymjbsfe1UWbaq9dMlVIBJGJhIOisPlpVHhKOaBeSwfHGaieyc0ViKFwL5zJy_QLOAMlVn-IEEctKcZHniJnqO7VEdTE_mWu65gtcXOWfrtrfhzxIQyRIZgPSbg_J4OnDNDZQzYBoU9LBbWcRX8zEIIiJ-ktnuLs2T93c","latitude":32.90083,"longitude":-97.114913,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":4.9,"reviews":null,"openNow":true,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CnRuAAAAcPGh9z8mZ1QU7JD_bn5LOgHSfUqrQMVKt-Oy1VHctFV4Hfs02cZ1s5KrGeKrBpkAyJOitz-uviEXfRRWVf7X2JZPy1Qa0_Buusgdbl9IeQRXz-lPePMxfyTNkRJLochK8W_ZSggKfCfDIUWp9HUHQxIQTc5ogsim3Ov8p6L_VO60fRoUEWsAeMJuA4uspVz6nUNK-HTsMh0","height":281,"width":284,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"3407 Lookout Ct, Grapevine, TX, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Plumber Inc","id":"0f55100d5bdf98af96cd76d86629a90ded8c9e89","reference":"CnRuAAAASj8u0xxro9jy_Z4OGOfZ3FSNaqhR2qrfW7PQabBDWizhQks49dn1x2QUCygwuG38-0uOgH2EzTzWzx8WafoaZhrcytPnopAk2stsqV3JclcVbrEiUBQ_61TOR9vKT7qbSyq2jgJVnk3NfYsmIFUPTRIQMS0cLuRxGb0iJkVaYt9BhhoU6HzBITIHXp0Mpfetokb7xwGLeA4","latitude":41.432029,"longitude":-87.354171,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":-1.0,"reviews":null,"openNow":null,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CnRnAAAAyZbeFQtJmSL4bMOZ3A7MItx5BK5l56uF_OXlnNDuQ1aF9Owk3wF5eJa2sufkWHmMyKHTPP7Yea9kXOa4GE61J_MmMb5wvKDml2WLOv0Hk4eeLFzrwJImesTj_x6tx2YmMQ-bta7UZQ2JXytUKVcFMhIQa5wNWM-cRPYrKAbqv8s4EBoU6xodmCOsmVQNRXDBraTpYGfGbG4","height":300,"width":525,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"1280 N Indiana Ave, Crown Point, IN, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png","types":["plumber","establishment"],"url":null},{"address":null,"name":"Dallas Plumbing Company","id":"000cd8825cb9f0f5e5e77a635a4179799137351c","reference":"CoQBegAAAOzZdOtTzElz1lMFi-8_yZqeImqaOF-5Z8GWHqa65OAH8insCBSoY-VUJOiOKsTZtDxi_XoZRE-mE5F-lC7lyS-mZXQ5oCfa95YyhzQHqxcdvyJ7jLSR_1eEg3sTWIuVpqZT-qArhxkR6SToIGl3iVoS-n0EmEV9tq1S0hqwAwuXEhBAYlvq9ubBRMMxtX8xim4tGhSs_xlPOhEuI050-I7ASHrmhqBJ2w","latitude":32.899274,"longitude":-96.701046,"vicinity":null,"website":null,"rating":3.0,"reviews":null,"openNow":false,"events":null,"utcOffset":-2147483648,"photos":[{"reference":"CqQBlgAAAKuYNIDjmeJV3k5qKk815jtdw4f4MJFO9rAoj61elDr5mkmuxpQUeVDbwA0LQTKDaHANTAkXHndsIkMaVXrBO-t7ZSvS7SMSdhWZobeZx2VILGfdwxRTAup_AbqUbOLeEG-Pn6owdppXT0tOGmpyoZKSn8dnYGHqf-XIonfcvzRSD9vlU3ZMjbU1xFYh48wWM-jfTyhTaFPu10FFWJXcqmkSEOYVxoJieb8VbjOxfg6Ze4saFKLIqYTAtguX0ueYX5BX-DosZejj","height":186,"width":288,"htmlAttributions":null}],"formattedAddress":"11055 Plano Rd, Dallas, TX, United States","intlPhoneNumber":null,"formattedPhoneNumber":null,"priceLevel":-1,"ratingCount":-1,"openingHours":null,"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png","types":["general_contractor","plumber","home_goods_store","store","establishment"],"url":null}],"companyList":[{"id":1,"companyName":"ABC Inc","companyDesc":"Household Company","companyAdd":"a","companyEmail":"a","alternateEmail":"a","phoneNumber":34234234,"altNumber":423423,"businessKeywords":"launfry, plumber, electrical, cleaning","ownerName":"324234"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `placeList` is array of arrays of objects. According to your `<li ng-repeat...` JSON should be following:

```
"placeList":[
    {
        "address":null,
        "name":"Len The Plumber"
    },
    {
        "address":null,
        "name":"Pete The Plumber"
    }
]
```

Alternatively you can update `ng-repeat` to output that format:

```
<ul ng-repeat="place in allresultsfinal.placeList">
    <li ng-repeat="all in place">{{ all.name }}<li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can, but you have to clarify which array has how many elements.

Comment: @brc_nd yes, you could, but you're asking the `ng-repeat` directive to look at an array as an individual entity, instead of it's entities.  You're looking for the name property on `[{}, {}]` instead of `{name: "", address: "" }`

Comment: Can u pls help out with a sample code for me to understand? I need to read name from placeList and companyName from companyList

Comment: @brc_nd Im0rtality shows you how in his answer, you have placelist as placeList : [ [ { }, { } ] ].  Remove the inner array, so it's simply [ { }, { } ]

Comment: {"placeList":[{"address":null,"name":"Len The Plumber"}],"companyList":[{"id":1,"companyName":"ABC Inc","companyDesc":"Household Company","companyAdd":"a","companyEmail":"a","alternateEmail":"a","phoneNumber":34234234,"altNumber":423423,"businessKeywords":"launfry, plumber, electrical, cleaning","ownerName":"324234"}]}

Comment: JSON is invalid. Apparently you have invalid symbol or something. Do you generate JSON by hand or do you use some method of serialization?

Comment: I am creating using spring controller

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/result/{tag}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public

Comment: Grab some hex editor and see that `"phoneNumber": ...` part. Something's not good there.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com - paste json there to validate. Invalid. Then retype mentioned part by hand. Valid. Something's wrong with json generation for sure. Maybe encoding or something like that.

Comment: i tried http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html and it validated my json

Comment: even the one u mentioned validated it. i tried with my long actual json

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49362/discussion-between-im0rtality-and-brc-nd)